# How do I run a simple python 2.7 project in codenvy?

Tags: codenvy

I'm trying to use codenvy.com to run a simple python 2.7 project, but I get this error:

```
[ERROR] testing-python2_unpack/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

what is the requirements.txt file, where to put it and what should it be to run a simple

```
print "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requirements.txt` lists the package dependencies for your project, to be installed alongside it -- it's an essential attribute of python packages.

You can probably get away with an empty file if your package has no dependencies -- just run

`$ touch requirements.txt`

to create an empty file in your package.

Comment: Couldn't use the console so I created it with the menu and I also had to create a main.py file, but it worked :-)